# Calculation of average day profile

Tags: r, mean, posixct

I have a data frame with a load profile for one year. The first column is stored as POSIXct by hour from "2011-01-01 00:00:00" to "2011-12-31 23:00:00". Second columns is stored as numeric with several data.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2,nrow = 8760))

df[,2] <- as.data.frame(rnorm(8760,50000,10000))

df[,1] <- as.data.frame(seq(from = as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 00:00:00"),
                           to = as.POSIXct("2011-12-31 23:00:00"),
                           by = "hours"))
```

I want to calculate an average day load profile. I've tried to work with the `xts package` and `period.apply` but I wasn't working. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. What is an average day profile?

Comment: Do you just want the mean of each day?

Comment: One day where the first hour is the mean of all the other first hours of the year, second hour is mean of all the other second hours and so on.

Comment: Create a 'grouping factor' from the hour of the day -- by formatting the time info down to just hour -- and the aggregate over all the hours using `mean()` as the aggregation function.

Comment: @Roland Es geht um Lastprofile im Stromnetz der Übertragungsnetzbetreiber in Deutschland.

Comment: What @DirkEddelbuettel said: `aggregate(x=df$V2, by=list(format(df$V1, "%H")), FUN=mean)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want something like:

```
aggregate(V2~format(V1,"%H"), data=df, FUN=mean)
```